# How specific is a makom kavuah?

Tags: halacha, makom-kavuah

Many shuls let people claim (buy) seats and put their name on the chair where they usually sit, making it "officially" their *makom kavuah*. Some of Mi Yodeya's other [makom-kavuah](/questions/tagged/makom-kavuah) questions also indicate that someone can claim a specific seat.

However, my father once told me that *makom kavuah* doesn't mean claiming a single specific seat - it's an area, a certain part of the shul where you usually sit.

What is the halachic definition of a *makom kavuah*? (Plus sources.)

Comment: You wan't to know makom kavuah as in the halacha that you should have one, or you want to know what is yours if you have a seat that you have the right to?

Comment: The second one.

Comment: You may want to make that clearer in the question, as I think the currently top voted answer doesn't actually have anything to do with that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two unrelated issues being conflated here.  One is the *halacha* of *makom kavuah*.  Your father is correct that it does not need to be a specific seat, as the Mogen Avrohom 90:34 writes that *makom kavuah* is satisfied within 4 amos.

However, if you buy a specific seat, then you have a right to that seat. I am not buying a "*makom kavuah*" but rather a specific place (or the rights to use a specific place at a certain time) in the Shul.

For one example in *halachic* literature where the exact location of the seats is clearly discussed, see [Minchos Yitzchok 9:154](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1601&st=&pgnum=216) where he discusses the exact number of seats away from the wall or the aisle.  The person bought and has a right to exactly the 10th seat or whichever seat it is.

While we're on the topic, I once saw a fascinating *teshuva* in which someone had purchased the aisle seat, and then the wall was knocked down and more seats were added.  He claimed that he had the right to the aisle seat and the shul said that his seat was in its original location and the new aisle seat was theirs to sell.  The Rov who was asked brought a very interesting proof - when the *yud* was taken from Sarai's name and replaced with the *hey*, the *yud* complained, and was consoled by being added to the beginning of Yehoshua's name.  However, isn't this a violation of the rights of the *hey* which was at the front of Yehoshua's name, and is now second?  You see from here that being at the front is not a right that has standing. (If I find where the Teshuva was, I'll source it)

Comment: Teshuva is in the Chasam Sofer if I remember correctly

Comment: +1 just for the Teshuvah that manages to find a nafkah minah from such an aggadeta.

Answer (score 2):

[Vayifga Bamakom](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=48272&st=&pgnum=3) quoting Magain Avraham 42 says that anything within an 8 Ama radius is considered the Makom Kavua.

Comment: So that's not really a general section of the shul. It's more like your usual chair plus or minus a seat on each side

Comment: Actually, I believe he is referring to a circle with a _diameter_ of 8, whose radius is therefore only 4.